# How to set up memory for Spark in a web application?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm running spark in single node.

My application (java-web) is using less memory than available.. I found this thread as useful.

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Setting-spark-executor-memory-problem-td11429.html.

From the link

> For local mode you only have one executor, and this executor is your
>   driver, so you need to set the driver's memory instead. *That said, in
>   local mode, by the time you run spark-submit, a JVM has already been
>   launched with the default memory settings, so setting
>   "spark.driver.memory" in your conf won't actually do anything for you.
>   Instead, you need to run spark-submit as follows
>
> bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 2g --class your.class.here app.jar

It suggests to use the `memory-flag` along with `bin/spark-submit` --for a jar file

But I'm running a maven-web applicaiton. Can I run this with spark-submit??

I set these in `spark-env.sh`  and run `source spark-env.sh` but still no change

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=10g
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just config these parameters in Spark's configuration files(*`spark/conf/spark-defaults.sh`*). And by the way, this is a better way than configuration in spark-shell unless you want to change it every time.

Comment: I set the 2 parameters(as updated in question) in `spark-env.sh ` but it is not affected..

Comment: do i need to add anything else??

Comment: Sorry, it should be the driver, so it is in `spark/conf/spark-defaults.sh` file.

Comment: any thing like restart required after setting it??

Comment: @Anil Yeah, you should restart your local 'cluster' after changing the configuration. Then it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Using `spark-env.sh` won't work in your setup since you're using a web application that uses its own runtime environment that in turn doesn't see the env vars. You can't use `spark-submit` either.

Given the comment about using local mode it means you need to tune in your JVM where the web app runs within and stop worrying about Spark. It will pick up the memory setting off the JVM since all services are running on the single JVM.

Comment: That won't work either. as given in the link I mentioned above, By the time I tell spark conf to set `.set("spark.executor.memory", [memory-size])` JVM has already UP & running with some memory.. I tried but failed to increase the memory

Comment: What Spark mode do you use? How is your master URL?

Comment: Single Node. And local host. I use `setMaster("localhost")`

Comment: You can't. There's no way `localhost` master URL could be accepted. It's illegal so I assume it's `local`. I highly recommend `local[*]` instead, though. See my improved answer.